# redundant question fields

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

These are simply pointing to known endpoints. This is truly 100% redundant data.

```
  "question_timeline_url": "/questions/3078600/timeline",
  "question_comments_url": "/questions/3078600/comments",
  "question_answers_url": "/questions/3078600/answers",
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/questions/803/redundant-data-in-users/808#808) for why these "endpoints" exist.