# redundant data in users

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

this is an example of truly redundant data. the paths are documented. they don't need to be included in the results.

```
   "user_questions_url": "/users/22656/questions",
   "user_answers_url": "/users/22656/answers",
   "user_favorites_url": "/users/22656/favorites",
   "user_tags_url": "/users/22656/tags",
   "user_badges_url": "/users/22656/badges",
   "user_timeline_url": "/users/22656/timeline",
   "user_mentioned_url": "/users/22656/mentioned",
   "user_comments_url": "/users/22656/comments",
   "user_reputation_url": "/users/22656/reputation",
```

Comment: I'd also like to know the reason for including all this redundancy.

Answer (score 3):

These are around because of popular demand in the private beta.

I have mixed feelings about them, honestly.

However, I'd rather not remove anything this late in the beta.

Comment: This late? How close are we to v1.0 then?

Comment: @George - the contest started [almost a month ago](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-contest/), and was expected to run for two.  Obviously we don't want to be changing the API under people right up until the deadline, so...

Comment: Ya, I realize that. Could we make it optional to include these?

Comment: @George - no.  They might be removed or re-purposed in a subsequent revision, but they're staying in v1.0 in all likelihood.

Comment: I personally like it.  It lets us know that that url that is being returned is, in fact, the url.  It'll allow you guys to possibly change it later on (for some unknown reason) and know that if the programmer wrote their app well it wouldn't break.